# Guacamole SSH Session recording using scriptreplay/typescript

Tags: ssh, tomcat

To those that have Apache Guacamole installed, and that are using it with the ssh extension to connect to resources, where/how do you have it set up either in configuration files or elsewhere to record sessions?

From what I can gather on the Guacamole install instructions: 
The full, raw text content of SSH sessions, including timing information, can be recorded automatically to a specified directory. This recording, also known as a "typescript", will be written to two files within the directory specified by typescript-path: NAME, which contains the raw text data, and NAME.timing, which contains timing information, where NAME is the value provided for the typescript-name parameter.

This format is compatible with the format used by the standard UNIX script command, and can be replayed using scriptreplay (if installed). For example, to replay a typescript called "NAME", you would run:
scriptreplay NAME.timing NAME

HOWEVER: Where do I initially configure the settings for this using:
typescript-path or create-typescript-path or typescript-name.
I simply cannot figure out what configuration file, or what command needs to be run and from where on the system to set this up to be able to log sessions.

I cannot seem to find any documentation on how to set this up so that I can view previous sessions.

Many thanks if you can please help!

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for this is at https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/1.0.0/gug/configuring-guacamole.html, under the **Text session recording (typescripts)** header.

This is enabled whenever a path is set in your connections settings.

Login the the web interface, go to `Settings > Connections > YourSSHServer` and set the path in the **Typescript (Text Session Recording)** section.

For example on my server I created a `/opt/guacamole-recordings` directory so that's the path to setup in the **Typescript path** field. I normally also put the server host name in the **Typescript name** otherwise the recordings will be saved as `typescript` and `typescript.timing`, `typescript.1` and `typescript.1.timing`, etc. making it difficult to find which one corresponds to any given server.

It's good practice to have your recordings directory mounted on a separate bug partition or on external/remote storage so you can plan to have plenty of space for recordings.

Having proper remote storage can make it easier to remotely access such recordings for conversion or playback from other (desktop) systems.